# Function variable and an array of functions in Chapel

Tags: function, chapel

In the following code, I'm trying to create a "function pointer" and an array of functions by regarding function names as usual variables:

```
proc myfunc1() { return 100; }
proc myfunc2() { return 200; }

// a function variable?
var myfunc = myfunc1;
writeln( myfunc() );

myfunc = myfunc2;
writeln( myfunc() );

// an array of functions?
var myfuncs: [1..2] myfunc1.type;

writeln( myfuncs.type: string );

myfuncs[ 1 ] = myfunc1;
myfuncs[ 2 ] = myfunc2;

for fun in myfuncs do
    writeln( fun() );
```

which seems to be working as expected (with Chapel v1.16)

```
100
200
[domain(1,int(64),false)] chpl__fcf_type_void_int64_t
100
200
```

So I'm wondering whether the above usage of function variables is legitimate? For creating an array of functions, is it usual to define a concrete function with desired signature first and then refer to its type (with `.type`) as in the above example?

Also, is it no problem to treat such variables as "usual" variables, e.g., pass them to other functions as arguments or include them as a field of class/record? (Please ignore these latter questions if they are too broad...) I would appreciate any advice if there are potential pitfalls (if any).

Comment: I can't help, but I want to know this one, too.

Comment: **Definitely a good point**. Besides the "freedom-of-expression" type of motivation, the way harder part, I guess, will be a principal ability to redistribute such a "pointer-to-Fun()" across the NUMA cluster-wide playgrounds and what will be **the final performance** ( viewed in an overhead-strict Amdahl-parallelism sense ) -- in other words, the actual costs of enabling such modus operandi in HPC domain. ( @roygvib a nice wish-list in your profile (y) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is using first class function support, which is prototype/draft in the Chapel language design. You can read more about the prototype support in the [First-class Functions in Chapel](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/firstClassFns.html) technote.

While many uses of first-class functions work in 1.16 and later versions, you can expect that the language design in this area will be revisited. In particular there isn't currently a reasonable answer to the question of whether or not variables can be captured (and right now attempting to do so probably results in a confusing error). I don't know in which future release this will change, though.

Regarding the `myfunc1.type` part, the section in the technote I referred to called "Specifying the type of a first-class function" presents an alternative strategy. However I don't see any problem with using `myfunc1.type` in this case.

Lastly, note that the `lambda` support in the current compiler actually operates by creating a class with a `this` method. So you can do the same - create a "function object" (to borrow a C++ term) - that has the same effect. A "function object" could be a record or a class. If it's a class, you might use inheritance to be able to create an array of objects that can respond to the same method depending on their dynamic type. This strategy might allow you to work around current issues with first class functions. Even if first-class-function support is completed, the "function object" approach allow you to be more explicit about captured variables. In particular, you might store them as fields in the class and set them in the class initializer. Here is an example creating and using an array of different types of function objects:

```
class BaseHandler {
  // consider these as "pure virtual" functions
  proc name():string { halt("base name called"); }
  proc this(arg:int) { halt("base greet called"); }
}
class HelloHandler : BaseHandler {
  proc name():string { return "hello"; }
  proc this(arg:int) { writeln("Hello ", arg); }
}
class CiaoHandler : BaseHandler {
  proc name():string { return "ciao"; }
  proc this(arg:int) { writeln("Ciao ", arg); }
}

proc test() {
  // create an array of handlers
  var handlers:[1..0] BaseHandler;
  handlers.push_back(new HelloHandler());
  handlers.push_back(new CiaoHandler());

  for h in handlers {
    h(1); // calls 'this' method in instance
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for detailed explanation. The "first-class function" page contains a lot of useful information. Now I understand that it is still a "beta" (or alpha)-like feature. So, as you suggested, it may be better to use a class or record object (with methods + parameters) and inherit it for customization. (Indeed, this may be simpler and more clear than passing a function that captures some global parameters...) I will play with them later. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your example you are using Chapel's [*initial* support for first-class functions](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/technotes/firstClassFns.html). To your second question, you could alternatively use a [function type helper](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/technotes/firstClassFns.html#specifying-the-type-of-a-first-class-function) for the declaration of the function array:

```
var myfuncs: [1..2] func(int);
```

These first-class function objects can be passed as arguments into functions – this is how [`Futures.async()`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/modules/packages/Futures.html#Futures.async) works – or stored as fields in a record ([Try It Online! example](https://tio.run/##dY6xDsIgEIZ3nuIfaWwcjEtLuvoKzkhp2gQpAWrbmD47niRVFxcu3P33fad66bRJSRkZAi6TVVcvndMeTwao0YaIztboaMIHG0vsTyEo4Pyo6DNE/idUZA4Q@yEcO4uGaCJ3wkSWY97NqI1tjD2kp8B@QgOr59@juJH3Wyv5UmfB@i5kgNdx8hYLDlgFNuLNfojaWP6BkZyfTyWqqqBxq42O@qsSKb0A)). Chapel's first-class function capabilities also include [lambda functions](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/technotes/firstClassFns.html#lambda-functions).

To be clear, the "initial" aspect of this support comes with the caveat (from the documentation):

> This mechanism should be considered a stopgap technology until we have developed and implemented a more robust story, which is why it's being described in this README rather than the language specification.

Comment: Thanks much for the related pages and TIO example. This "func()" is exactly what I was wondering about (i.e., how to define a signature or prototype in Chapel). But I slightly feel that the name "func" might be a bit confusing because it is very general... (so "functype" or "proctype" etc might be a more clear alternative? though not sure...) I will try the TIO example later. Thanks much :)